# Make request from remote computer with using PowerShell

Tags: networking, powershell, httpwebrequest

I am looking a way to make web request from remote computer. There a 10 servers shared in one network and I need make web request from each server for example to 'http://google.com'. So, I am going to using PowerShell and started writing the script. But I don't know how make request on behalf of server1, server2.. server10

```
$hosts = @("server1Ip", "server2Ip", ..,"server10Ip");
$url = "http://google.com"
$hLen = $hosts.Length;

for ($i=0; $i -lt $hLen; $i++)
{
    try 
    {
        Write-Host "Pinging web address for server: $url ..."
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        Write-Host "Web Request Succeeded."   
    } catch 
    {
        Write-Host ("Web Request FAILED!!! The error was '{0}'." -f $_)
    } finally 
    {
        if ($response) 
        {
            $response.Close()
            Remove-Variable response
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use invoke-command and wrap your code into the sciptblock like :

```
icm -computername $hosts -scriptBlock{
try 
    {
        Write-Host "Pinging web address for server: $url ..."
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://google.com")
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        Write-Host "Web Request Succeeded."   
    } catch 
    {
        Write-Host ("Web Request FAILED!!! The error was '{0}'." -f $_)
    } finally 
    {
        if ($response) 
        {
            $response.Close()
            Remove-Variable response
        }
    }
}
```